# parsing error in xml Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am trying to parse an xml file. I am getting the error: `Cannot call method 'on' of undefined`. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? How do I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ed Spencer</name>
        <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Abe Elias</name>
        <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

**This is my store**

```
Ext.define('TestXml.store.Test', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId : 'testStore',
    model : 'TestXml.model.Test',
    autoLoad : 'true',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'test.xml',
        reader : {
            type : 'xml',
            record: 'user',
            rootProperty :'users'
        }
    }


});
```

**This is my model**

```
Ext.define('TestXml.model.Test', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
        name : 'id',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        type : 'string'
    }



]
```

});

**This is my app.js**

```
items: [{

         xtype : 'combo',
          store : 'testStore', //loading the store
           minWidth : 50,
            minHeight :30,
            displayField :'id',
             valueField :'name'

          }]
```

Thanks

Comment: The code looks fine. I reckon the issue is outside the code you have provided. Can you give more details, like the call stack leading to the error. Also, are you sure the store is in scope when the application loads? That is, does the application has `stores` config properly set (or the controllers of which)?